# Determine $r\in\mathbb{R}$ subject to $\frac{(2r+\sqrt{2r})^2}{(2r-\sqrt{2r})^2}=34$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Determine $r\in\mathbb{R}$ subject to $\frac{(2r+\sqrt{2r})^2}{(2r-\sqrt{2r})^2}=34$.

I had tried using rationalisation but its not getting me the correct answer and instead I got one irrational number in root which does not approximately equal to $34$.

Comment: Prove? Maybe "Find $r$ such that"

Comment: yeah u can say so

Comment: How is this question ‘abstract’? ‘algebra-precalculus’ is indeed a more appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{(2r+\sqrt{2r})^2}{(2r-\sqrt{2r})^2} = 34\\
\Leftrightarrow (2r+\sqrt{2r})^2 = 34(2r-\sqrt{2r})^2\\
\Leftrightarrow 4r^2 + 2\sqrt{2r}+2r=34(4r^2 - 2\sqrt{2r}+2r)\\
\Leftrightarrow -132r^2+70\sqrt{2} \sqrt{r}-66r = 0
$$

Substitute $u=\sqrt{r}$ to get
$$
-132u^4-66u^2+70\sqrt{2} u = 0
$$

which is a biquadratic formula. Can you take it from here?

Comment: It is probably easier to solve $$
 \pm \sqrt {34}  = \frac{{2r + \sqrt {2r} }}{{2r - \sqrt {2r} }} = 1 + \frac{2}{{\sqrt {2r}  - 1}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{2r}=x$

Your equation is
$$\frac{x+1}{x-1} = \pm \sqrt{34}$$

or $$x =\frac{\pm \sqrt{34}+1}{\pm \sqrt{34}-1}$$

Therefore, $$r =\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\pm \sqrt{34}+1}{\pm \sqrt{34}-1} \right)^2$$